# Can we assign an object to a html element in plain JavaScript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I want to store an object as an attribute of an HTML element! Let's suppose I'm having a div element and when I click the div element I want to get the values of the object from the div element so that I can use it in the click function.

I've seen people doing it in jquery but I want it in pure javascript since I'm writing a typescript code and I don't want jQuery

```
ex: 
var myNewObject={
"first_name": "Sam",
"last_name": "carter"
}
var div=document.getElementByID("myID");
div.setAttribute("myobject",myNewObject);

<div onclick="somefunc()>
</div>
function somefunc()
{
     console.log(document.getAttribute("myobject").first_name);

}
```

Expected output:
   Sam
   Actual output: 
   Error

Comment: Attributes are for simple data only. But you can attach anything to the element objects directly: `document.getElementById('id_here').foobar = {"bar":"baz"};` localStorage or your own object to keep track of data might suit your needs better though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store any Javascript objects on an `HTMLElement` directly:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.myobject = { hello: 'world' };
```

Only strings can be stored in attributes, and the string representation of an object is `[object Object]`. If you **must** use attributes you can serialize the object and store it and then deserialize it when you retrieve it again:

```js
const obj = { hello: 'world' };
const a = document.querySelector('#a');
a.setAttribute('myobject', JSON.stringify(obj));

const obj2 = JSON.parse(a.getAttribute('myobject'));
console.log(obj2.hello);
```

```html
<div id="a">Hello</div>
```

Storing state in DOM is *generally* considered bad practice in any case.

Comment: hello @Phillip! The set attribute code worked! thanks a lot! I didn't get the idea of stringifying it earlier. Coming to the assigning of the object to HTMLElement directly, I'm not able to do that! I want you to know I'm using typescript! *"I'm getting an issue property doesn't exist on HTMLElement"*

Comment: You would either have to augment the `HTMLElement` (or the specific element) type with the property you wish to add, or just cast to any: `(element as any).myobject = ...`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach. This is a good time to learn about [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is similar to an object but the key can be any type, not just strings. You can use the element as a key and the object as the value.

```
const elementMap = new Map();
const myElement = document.querySelector("#myElement");
const myObject = {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0};
elementMap.set(myElement, myObject);
...
//later we can access the object by that element
const myElement = document.querySelector("#myElement");
const myObject = elementMap.get(myElement);
```

Here are two big advantages of this approach.
1. No need to worry about name collisions with properties of the HTML element, or possibly other code modifying the element's properties.
2. The object is the same object you originally had, which can be important if you care about the reference which is not preserved if you use the JSON string solution.